# Multi targeting in .NET, but no `TargetFramework` tag

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-4.5

I've got a .NET Framework class library that I'd like to be able to build for .NET Core 2.1 as well as .NET Framework. There are [loads of](http://www.ben-morris.com/sharing-libraries-between-net-core-and-net-framework-applications/) [blogs on this topic](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/22/MultiTargeting-and-Porting-a-NET-Library-to-NET-Core-20), but they all assume that there is a `TargetFramework` tag in your .csproj file that you can convert to being a plural and then use with semi-colon delineation.

My .csproj file doesn't have a `TargetFrameworks` tag.

It does have this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{...}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>LibraryName</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>LibraryName</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

How can I compile it for .NET Core 2.1 as well?

Comment: Create a .NET Standard class library and edit it by hand. See duplicate.

Comment: So I can't use my existing project? As I mentioned I've seen a number of similar blog posts and threads, but I've already got a project that doesn't use the `TargetFramework` tag in its csproj file (which I why I felt it wasn't a duplicate). I've got an existing .NET Framework 4.5 that I want to multi-target for .NET Core 2.1.